# NavBar using classlist toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sir/Madam,
I have a problem with my hamburger menu. when i click on the menu, the 3lines cross, but the nav-list doesn't open

**HERE IS THE LINK**
https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-fast-oefqbt

Comment: Please post your code here... so you toggle class in your hamburger menu is this correct?

Comment: The preference for posting code is by posting it as text, not as a link. It is easier to see in one look if the problem is similar for someone else, which is the point of Stackoverflow, helping eachother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue. Please find this example.

https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-hooks-yq2wj8